# Is there a way of finding the Observable/Unobservable decomposition using python (maybe from the control libarary)?

Tags: python, controls, system, decomposition, observability

I am currently working on a project where I need to decompose my system into observable and unobservable subsystems in an efficient way, so I was looking for a function that could help me with that.

PS: I know about this function and it is not was I am looking for:

```
s = co.ss(A, B, C, D)

sys, T = co.observable_form(s)
```

In this case, the system needs to be fully observable.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone is looking for an answer to this, I found a great library that has a function that does just this. It is called "harold" and you can find it [here](https://github.com/ilayn/harold/tree/79341cc08b8659278e288a5bada29bc1a342a833). The said function is called "staircase" and it is equivalent to the [obsvf](https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/obsvf.html?s_tid=doc_ta) or [ctrbf](https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/ctrbf.html) functions from MATLAB; it implements the Staircase Algorithm.